# NFSv4 slow copying from client to server

Tags: nfs

Although all my computers have been running Linux for at least 15 years, I consider myself a cookbook admin.  Meaning I web search and then do a lot of copy/paste what seems to be the most correct answer.

Server – Debian Bookworm updated. No GUI. Nfs, ssh, emby only programs installed.  Harddrive is WD Red Pro. Aquota Not installed.
The fstab mount line
UUID=”the uuid is here” /srv/serTV      ext4    defaults        0       2

The line in exports file
/srv/serTV        10.1.1.0/24(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)

cleint – Debian Bookworm updated. Mate desktop

The fstab mount line
10.1.1.11:/srv/serTV /home/me/Hard-Drives/Server-TV                                   nfs       user,rw,nofail,hard,intr 0 0

Copying from client to server is really slow.  Been running the server for several yrs without issue.  I think the problem started when I updated to bookworm about 2 months ago.  At first caja file manager copied fast and then would show the file 100% copied, but take a long time to finish.  Now it copies slow and takes a long time to finish.  I have three hard drive set up the same way and it’s the same with all three.  All have at least 20% free space.  For some reason the nfsstat command doesn’t work.
I'll upload the nfs logs if someone will tell me how to get them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your question and use some of the formatting tools available in the post editor to present the information you have provided more clearly? Also, do you mean "copying" instead of "coping"?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to this forum.  What kind of editing do you mean.

Comment: The is an EDIT button immediately below your post. Please click that and look around at the options there for formatting the text.